# GDAL online courses and Books with tutorials

Tags: gdal, ogr, references

I feel I have progressed well with some GDAL functionality including some novel uses of calc but I feel I am missing so much more. I would like to learn more particularly when it comes to raster data processing. Website resources are great but often lack explanation or examples and hence I come to this board for help. **I am looking for quality GDAL online courses or books with tutorials** (earlier questions have focused on general GDAL learning materials but I am looking particularly for online courses or texts with tutorials). Low-cost options are fine. Below is progress thus far.

**Courses**

1. [Introduction to GDAL](https://gisadvisor.wordpress.com/2016/04/15/current-course-offerings/)
2. The course listed on the GDAL website is now a broken link (http://cosmicproject.org/OGR.)
3. The Penn State (GEOG 585) one is web focused not processing focused.

**Books**

- Geospatial Power Tools